# Error opening eclipse in archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, java, eclipse

So I am running archlinux.
On `java -version` my output is:

```
java version "1.7.0_101"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.6) (Arch Linux build 7.u101_2.6.6-1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

I have installed with pacman the `eclipse-java` package.
When I start eclipse I am getting the following error and eclipse crushes.
[image]

How to pass this and run eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse now requires Java 8 and you're using Java 1.7, this won't work. Install `jdk8-openjdk` instead and/or wait for [the bug in Arch Linux' bug tracker](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/49848) to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you Wieland. I have just set the java 1.8 and it is working smooth. For anyone who must do this, can use `archlinux-java set  java-8-openjdk`

Answer (score 0):

FYI for Arch Linux users: Even though Arch Linux pacman gives the option to install jdk9-openjdk within the eclipse-common package (September 30, 2017), Eclipse Oxygen.1 (4.7.1) will not work with version 9.  Install jdk8-openjdk instead. Use script "archlinux-java set java-8-openjdk" if another openjdk version is installed.  Eclipse will work fine thereafter.